# future perfect sounds weird to me

Tags: grammar

"I will have passed my test by winter." sounds weird to me, how can a person living in the present, know something will be completed at some point in the future?

is a future perfect tense used when something is hoped. or to show someone's unfounded confidence?

Comment: If it's "something hoped", you might say *"**I hope [that]** I will have passed my test by winter"*. If you don't have confidence in your future success, perhaps *"**I doubt [that]** I will have passed my test by winter"*. Where unqualified *"I will have passed my test by winter"* is a simple assertion about the future. What exactly don't you understand here?

Comment: "I will have finished this drink by the time you get back from the bar with the next one, so hurry up." Absolute certainty of a future event which will very soon become a past event.

Comment: I am on a train that gets to London at 20:00. I can say 'by 21:00 I will have arrived in London'.

Comment: This seems a question about philosophy rather than the English language. How can you know something about the present or the past?

Comment: will is used for belief. If you believe it, you can use "will". Please see: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/will-would#:~:text=We%20use%20will%3A,or%20are%20willing%20to%20do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you don't know whether you will pass the test or not (you can add "I hope" to the sentence!), but we often say that, if all goes according to plan, we will have done something by a certain time in the future.

> I will have finished work by 6 p.m.
>
> I don't know my sister's fiancé yet, but I will have met him several times by the wedding day.

It doesn't have to involve hope or overconfidence, just a simple prediction.

Comment: I'll just add that this goes for claims about future in general. "Don't call me at seven, I'll be having dinner." "Let's run the test and then we will know what the issue is." It could turn out otherwise, but this is what I *expect* to happen.